# Why does S-Function only execute mdlInitializeSizes() and does not execute mdlOutputs(), mdlStart() etc?

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

#define S_FUNCTION_NAME  myfunction_sFun

#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2

#define MDL_INITIAL_SIZES

#define MDL_INITIALIZE_SAMPLE_TIMES

#include "tmwtypes.h"

#include "simstruc_types.h"

#include "mex.h"

#include "simstruc.h"

void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)

{

```
ssPrintf("Initialize\n");

  //My code has been removed from here

ssPrintf("End Initialize\n");
```

}

void mdlInitializeSampleTimes(SimStruct *S)

{

```
ssPrintf("Sample Times\n");
```

}

#define MDL_OUTPUTS

#ifdef  MDL_OUTPUTS

void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)

{

```
ssPrintf("Outputs\n");
```

}

#endif

#define MDL_START

#ifdef  MDL_START

void mdlStart(SimStruct *S)

{

```
ssPrintf("Start\n");
```

}

#endif

void mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S){}

/*=============================*

- Required S-function trailer *

  *=============================*/

#ifdef  MATLAB_MEX_FILE    /* Is this file being compiled as a MEX-file? */

#include "simulink.c"      /* MEX-file interface mechanism */

#else

#include "cg_sfun.h"       /* Code generation registration function */

#endif

Comment: When I run my s-function (either in MATLAB or via simulink diagram), I only see the "Initialize" and "End Initialize" outputs. The s-function never executes the other mdl* functions. Does anyone know why this could be? I've also verified this by attaching the MATLAB process to Visual Studio and debugging - breakpoints in every function except mdlInitializeSizes are not reached.

Comment: Your question has problems with the code formatting. Also your comment should be part of the question itself.

Comment: Do you try to compile your code? In this case, sometimes you should have a look at the tlc-file (if it exists in your case). There might be some functions left out there, and therefore they will not get called.

Answer (score 1):

`mdlStart` and `mdlOutputs` are option methods that only get called in certain circumstances.  For instance, `mdlOutputs` only gets called if there are any outputs defined - which in your case there aren't.  (I am a little surprised that `mdlStart` is not being called.)

See the documentation [Simulink Engine Interaction with C S-Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/how-the-simulink-engine-interacts-with-c-s-functions.html) for which methods are optional, and their calling sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil. I removed some of the code I have in order to post but my mdlInitializeSizes() defines outputs for my s-function (I believe this is what you're talking about). I will look at the documentation and see if I find anything that stands out - will loop back here when/if I resolve this issue.